# foreach php logic issue

Tags: php

I got 4 records in the carts db. I got the result: 4444. How can I change the result to 1234 instead?

View:

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($carts AS $cart) {
    $x = $i+1;
    echo $x;
}
```

Controller:

```
function confirm() {
    $orders = $this->data;
    $sessionId = $this->passedArgs['ct_session_id'];
    $this->set('data', $sessionId );
    $carts = $this->Cart->find(
        'all', 
        array('conditions' => array('Cart.ct_session_id' => $sessionId), 'recursive' => 1)
    );
    $this->set(compact('carts', 'orders'));         
}
```

Comment: How'd you get 4444 anways, that code would produce 1111.

Comment: `implode('', range(1,4))` but I guess it's not, what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
foreach($carts as $cart) {
    $i++;
    echo $i;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to increment $i each time you execute this instruction, so you has to write :
`$x = ++$i;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = count($carts);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
  echo $i."</br>";
}

?>
```